# Conditional validation on model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view & model that I use for both the edit and the insert page for a record. One of the business requirements is that a certain field is required on edit but not on new. Originally before this particular feature was added to the docket, i had the model like so:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
[Range(0.0, (double)decimal.MaxValue)]
[DisplayName("Cost")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal ProposedCost { get; set; }
```

I would like to either remove the required property if it is an insert form, or add it if an edit form. What is the better approach? All my other validation is done like above. Or can I alter the model state? Thoughts?

EDIT

Something I should clarify is that they are still permitted to insert a cost on new, just not required.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you're on MVC3/.NET4, you can use `IValidatableObject` which exists specifically for such purposes.

Quoting [ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx),

> ...The IValidatableObject interface enables you to perform model-level
>   validation, and enables you to provide validation error messages
>   specific to the state of the overall model....

You model would look like

```
public class MyViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public decimal? ProposedCost { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
    { 
        if (Id != null && ProposedCost == 0) {
            yield return new ValidationResult("ProposedCost must be provided.");
        }
    }
}
```

and then in the controller,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        //failed - report an error, redirect to action etc
    }
    //succeeded - save to database etc
}
```

---

Otherwise, the most clean solution would be to use view models - `UpdateViewModel` where the property is required, and `CreateViewModel` where it's not required.

Comment: I tried this, however was still able to save an edit record without a proposed cost. I placed a breakpoint and was hitting the Validationresult. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure you check `ModelState.IsValid`? I updated the answer to show an example. Also note that `ProposedCost` needs to be nullable if we allow not to set it.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that, good catch. The other properties added have a client side check automatically behind the scenes. Anyway can I tap into that? This is of course beyond the scope of my original question.

Comment: tried this and I was able to yield a new Validation result but my, "ModelState.IsValid" was still true... Not sure why.

Comment: it was using yield for some reason it didn't like.. so I just newd up a IEnumerable<ValidationResult> and added errors if found otherwise returned the object empty or not.. That worked using MVC4.

Answer (score 4):

There is the MVC Foolproof library: http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

For example you would need to have something like this in your model:

```
[RequiredIfTrue("Required", ErrorMessage = "*")]
[Range(0.0, (double)decimal.MaxValue)]
[DisplayName("Cost")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal ProposedCost { get; set; }

public bool Required { get; set; }
```

You would then need to set the `Required` property based on which form the model is going to.

You will also need a hidden input field on the form to represent the `Required` property if you wish to perform client side validation.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `RequiredIf` validation attribute from the [MVC Foolproof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) project.
I've used it on projects to enable just the functionality you require.

An alternative would be to use the [`RemoteAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) and implement the logic yourself in a method.

Comment: I personally don't like `RequiredIf` because it's not type safe - you have to write `[RequiredIf("SomeProperty", value, ...)]` and it means the compiler won't warn you if `SomeProperty` gets renamed but the old name was stuck in the attribute

Comment: @andreister you can use `[RequiredIf(nameof(SomeProperty), value, ...)]` which gives you compile time validation and copes withe the renaming of `SomeProperty`

Comment: Very true @JamesCulshaw - one of my favourite C# 6 features, because it helps this exact scenario.

Comment: Yeah my comment was from 2013 and now we finally have `nameof` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try on validation with:

```
ModelState.Remove("ProposedCost");
```

Or extending your model like this:

```
public class NewModeViewModel : EditModeViewModel
{
   public new decimal ProposedCost { get; set; }
}
```

and passing to the edit view.