# MVC unobtrusive validation - Custom validator that depends on a previous selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have a standard address form with a number of fields. e.g.

- Address line 1
- Address line 2
- Country
- State
- Postal code

The problem is that the "state" field should be a required field *only* when "country" is set to USA. If the country is set to anything else, then it should *not* be required.  I could handle it in the controller but I'd like to do it on the client side unobtrusively.  Any suggestions?

Comment: pls send your View page code

Comment: You could implement `IValidatableObject`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970584/conditional-validation-on-model-in-mvc) and all over the Internet and SO for an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just wrote a quick demo for your requirement.

```
// model
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfCountryIsUSA]
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}


// Validation Attribute
public class RequiredIfCountryIsUSA : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public RequiredIfCountryIsUSA()
    {

    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var countryPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty("Country");
        var countryValue = countryPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null).ToString();
        if (countryValue == "USA" && (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString().Trim())))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("State is required when Country is USA");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ErrorMessage = "State is required when country is USA";
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("country", "USA");
        rule.ValidationType = "iscountryusa";

        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

client side javascript

```
(function ($) {
$.validator.addMethod("iscountryusa", function (state, element, country) {
    var country = $('#Country').val();

    if (country == 'USA' && state == '') {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("iscountryusa", "country");
} (jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out MVC Foolproof. http://foolproof.codeplex.com/.
You can NuGet the package into your solution.

It has attributes such as these which may help you;

```
[RequiredIf]
[RequiredIfNot]
[RequiredIfTrue]
[RequiredIfFalse]
[RequiredIfEmpty]
[RequiredIfNotEmpty]
[RequiredIfRegExMatch]
[RequiredIfNotRegExMatch]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom validation attribute, deriving from `ValidationAttribute`. Take the name of the dependent property (in this case, Country) as a parameter for the constructor, and override the `IsValid` method, in which you will specify the validation logic which will use this dependent property.

Now, if you also want to enable this validation unobtrusively on client-side, you need to implement the `IClientValidatable` interface in your custom validation attribute, and then you will need to write the same validation logic in a JavaScript method. Also, you will need to add this method to the list of jQuery unobtrusive validation adapters.

You can read up more [here](http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/custom-unobtrusive-jquery-validation-with-data-annotations-in-mvc-3/), [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784943/asp-net-mvc-3-client-side-validation-with-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I make it simple using js file. I created the Js file named it as "CountryValidate.js" and written like this

```
var list = ["India", "Australia", "Pakisthan"];
 $(document).ready(function(){
        debugger
        $("#Country").keyup(function () {
            debugger
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if ($("#Country").val() !== list[i]) {
                    $("#error").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#error").hide();
                    break;
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

and added some statements in the view(Student.cshtml)
I added the this property for the Country Name Text Box

```
<span class="validation has-error text-danger" id="error" hidden>Invalid Country Name</span>
```

The Changes i made it for the Textbox to display the validation message.