# Only one error message per custom validation in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have not been able to find a definitive answer about this. In asp.net MVC 5, when some fields are required only if some condition is true, we will need to implement a custom validation attribute by inheriting from ValidationAttribute. So, I have this:

```
public class RegistrationValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
   protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
      RegistrationModel model = (RegistrationModel)value;
      if (model.IsNewbie)
      {
           if (model.SelectedCoachId == 0)
           {
               return new ValidationResult("Since you are a newbie, you have to select a coach.");
           }

           if (model.SelectedDominantHand == 0)
           {
               return new ValidationResult("If you are a newbie, you have to tell us if you are a leftie or rightie.");
           }
      } 

      return ValidationResult.Success;

   }
}
```

But, this will only return 1 error message even if the registrant says that he is a newbie and does not select a coach nor specify his dominant hand.  I wish that the ValidationResult class had a constructor that takes a collection of error messages.

So, do I have to split this custom validation attribute into 2 custom validation attribute classes, one of which says MustSelectCoachIfNewbieAttribute and the other one says MustSpecifyDominantHandIfNewbieAttribute?

Is it possible to accomplish this in a single custom validation attribute class?  Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just return a List<ValidationResult>?

Comment: Is that even an option? The method signature says it returns a ValidationResult instead of a collection of ValidationResult.

Comment: Of course.  In our application (MVC3) we employ a custom validation engine which returns a list of ValidationResult, and adds them to the ModelState via ModelState.AddModelError.  But you may only need something like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2012/09/07/flexible-conditional-validation-with-asp-net-mvc-adding-client-side-support.aspx

Comment: Ha, this RequiredIfAttribute looks very interesting.  Will give it a shot. Thank you. It should be built into the official MVC framework.

Comment: @BrendanGreen: Apparently, the idea of returning a list of ValidationResult does not work because the method IsValid specifies that it returns a ValidationResult. If I attempt to return a list of ValidationResult, I will get a compile error which says: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>' to 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult'`

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970584/conditional-validation-on-model-in-mvc

Comment: Thanks, looks like it is indeed the case that a custom validation attribute class that inherits from ValidationAttribute can only return one error message.  I guess I might as well just implement the IValidatableObject interface like you suggested.