# dynamically remove an element's required attribute in ASP MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

Is there a way, in an ASP MVC project using unobtrusive validation, to dynamically remove the Required attribute from an element?

The element is decorated with a Required annotation in the view model.  I thought I could remove this by removing the html attribute, "data-val-required," with JQuery but client validation still treats the element as required.  Is it impossible to manipulate the element's validation by manipulating the unobtrusive validation attributes?

This is what I tried, but it didn't work.  I wanted to remove the required attribute if a check box was unchecked.

```
$("#chkTempHire").click(function () {

    var checked = $(this).attr("checked");
    var attr = $("#txtTempHireEndDate").attr("data-val-required");
    var hasAttr = false;

    if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false)
        hasAttr = true;

    if (!checked && hasAttr)
        $("#txtTempHireEndDate").removeAttr("data-val-required");
});
```

Am I missing something, or is it just not possible?

Thank you!

Comment: One solution is to use MVC's [Foolproof Validation](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/), which allows you to use attributes such as `RequiredIf`.

Comment: Conditional validation is what you're looking for, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970584/conditional-validation-on-model-in-mvc

Comment: Thanks, I am using FluentValidation and it works for me.  I've just been trying to learn more about how the unobtrusive validation works.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `.rules()` method built into jQuery, you don't need to manually remove attributes.

To remove:

```
$("#txtTempHireEndDate").rules("remove", "required")
```

To add:

```
$("#txtTempHireEndDate").rules("add", "required")
```

Comment: Success!!  Thanks so much.

Comment: Very standard, neat & clean approach.

Answer (score 2):

you can use rules function in jquery.validate

```
$("..").rules("add",....)
$("..").rules("remove",...)
```

http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules

Answer (score 0):

You must revalidate the form.

Just call the validate function from form, like this:

```
$('#FormId').valid();
```

You can also validate the control you've removed the attribute:

```
$('#txtTempHireEndDate').valid();
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#dailyFlow").removeAttr('data-val-required');

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Please add an explanation, especially the difference and benefits in comparison to the other answers.