# How to dynamically handle the required validation in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How to dynamically handle the required validation in mvc ?

In the view :- .cshtml

```
<button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
<button type="submit" id="previewButton">Preview</button>
```

In the ViewModel

```
public class myProjectViewModel 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Testing Mandatory Field")]
    public int? MyId { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to inherit the Interface : IValidatableObject by implementing RequiredIf condition on it.

```
[RequiredIf("previewButton",0, ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Testing Mandatory Field")]
    public int? MyId { get; set; }
```

I added this remove rules in Jquery as well.

```
  $("#previewButton").click(function () {
        $("#MyId").rules("remove", "required");
    });
```

At present, I am validating the field MyId as requried field for both Submit and  Preview.

I will have to validate only for Submit Button and for Preview Button there is no validation required.

Comment: what do your controller actions look like? do you have separate actions?

Comment: Check on this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466002/dynamically-remove-an-elements-required-attribute-in-asp-mvc

Comment: In controller, i have separate action for Create and Edit.  Is there a way to false proof the action based on Html Input Id

Comment: Are you talking about server side validation or client side validation ?

Comment: I tried implementing the Jquery. that doesnt work. So , i will have to do the FalseProof validation on Model

Comment: I am trying to get HTML Button Input Id : previewButton to the Model.  Saying, RequiredIf : Button Click is previewButton , Skip the validation