# how to set validation according dropdown selection in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

Here is my View code:

```
<div class="form-group-1">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.device.HasAMC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-4" })
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.device.HasAMC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
 </div>
 <div class="form-group-1" id="HasDate">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.device.AMCExpiredDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-4" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.device.AMCExpiredDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "AMCExpireDate(MM/dd/yyyy)", required = "required", title = "Enter AMC Expire Date" } })
 </div>
<button style="margin-left:33%;" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary col-lg-2 " type="button" name="action" onclick="javascript:Save(@ViewBag.DealerId);" value="SaveDeviceInfo"><strong>Save</strong></button>
```

In this I need to set required field "AMCExpiredDate" like if value of "HasAMC" selected "true" then apply validation for required field and if it is false then remove validation from "AMCExpiredDate".

Is this possible in MVC? 
Please Help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Consider a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` or similar validation attribute (or you can write your own)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional validation on model in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970584/conditional-validation-on-model-in-mvc)

Comment: just do it with jquery,on onchange event, add the validation attribute to the dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Change your view to something like this

```
 <div class="form-group-1">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.device.HasAMC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-4" })
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.device.HasAMC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
     </div>
     <div class="form-group-1" id="HasDate">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.device.AMCExpiredDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-4" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.device.AMCExpiredDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "AMCExpireDate(MM/dd/yyyy)", required = "required", title = "Enter AMC Expire Date" } })

        // put validation-error  
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.device.AMCExpiredDate);
                                    @if (@ViewData.ModelState["AMCExpiredDate"] != null && @ViewData.ModelState["AMCExpiredDate"].Errors.Count > 0)
                                    {
                                        <br/>
                                        <span class="field-validation-error col-md-10" style="margin-left: -14px;">
                                        @ViewData.ModelState["AMCExpiredDate"].Errors[0].ErrorMessage.Trim()
                                    </span>
                                    }

     </div>
    <button style="margin-left:33%;" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary col-lg-2 " type="button" name="action" onclick="javascript:Save(@ViewBag.DealerId);" value="SaveDeviceInfo"><strong>Save</strong></button>


            // create hidden field of your model variables
                 @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => model.device.HasAMC)
                 @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => model.device.HasAMC)
```

> on Server Side

```
public ActionResult SaveMarks(mymodelClass model)

            if (model.device.HasAMC)
            {
               // validat you AMCExpiredDate expir date e.georgian
               if(model.device.AMCExpiredDate == null)
               {
                ModelState.AddModelError("AMCExpiredDate", "Please Proive you AMCExpiredDate");
               }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need this on client side only not server side.

Comment: Then it is not that big problem all you need is put a Validation logic behind button function "onclick="javascript:Save(@ViewBag.DealerId);"
e.g 
code

 if($('#HasAMC').val() === true) {
           // Validate the date
    }