# How to display error message under right element in the UI

Tags: c#, angularjs, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

I have these two view model properties that has these validation attributes.

```
[CardTypeValidation(ErrorMessage = "Card type is mandatory")]
public CCardType CardType { get; set; }

[CardNumberValidation("CardType", ErrorMessage = "Card type is not a right match for the card number provided")]
public string CardNumber { get; set; }
```

Now my problem is all validation works fine but the error message "Card type is not a right match for the card number provided" is displayed underneath the Card number textbox. (Which is right below the Card Type dropdown).

My tester is after that the message should be displayed under the Card Type dropdown.

If I put this attribute on the Card Type, then it has some wierd exception and not proper validation either. So its just the message instead of getting displayed under the card number, it should display under the card type. How to do that?

**EDIT**

Can I force the error on Card Number attribute to Card Type?

All of my UI is Angular and hence do not ask for html helper for validation.

Comment: Show your view  - If you have `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CardNumber)` then just positioned it where you want the message to be displayed.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I am afraid I do not see these helper to show the error message but we use a custom form which we call in all places under every element as a class.

Comment: Without seeing your code, its impossible to help.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I learned from my lead that we use angular. So no ASP.NET MVC html helper validations. Please help?

Comment: No one can guess what your code is  :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I will not be able to change anything in the UI but hard code. My UI code is just using the server error

Comment: @StephenMuecke: My simple question is, can I force the error message on this Card Number property to Card Type? I mean to display in Card Type?

Comment: May be this can help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252170/how-to-set-validation-according-dropdown-selection-in-mvc/37253325?noredirect=1#comment62060046_37253325